# Plugin for sharing on social sites?

Tags: plugins

I'm looking for a plugin that enables sharing an article on sites like Facebook, Twitter and LinkeIn. One catch is that I want a plugin that respect the privacy of the user and doesn't include trackware/spyware on the page. Can anyone recommend a good plugin for this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sociable](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sociable/) adds sharing links for any social network sites you want (configurable).  To my knowledge, it doesn't add any trackware on the page (I have yet to see an officially hosted plugin do that).

Answer (score 0):

[AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) is awesome. The plugin for WordPress works well, but I prefer to use their API to customize the experience. I use this on everything.

Comment: Isn't AddThis just spyware? Use flash cookies to track the users on multiple sites?

Comment: According to the http://www.addthis.com/blog/2009/01/05/the-addthis-flash-cookie-we-need-your-feedback/, they stopped using Flash cookies for tracking. See also  http://www.addthis.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=24424

Comment: Sorry, but I don't trust these people. Also they include a script in the page which definitive could be used for tracking users. <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#username=xa-xxx"></script>

Comment: Username in that exact instance is YOUR username, your account on AddThis for tracking analytics statistics from usage, not a username of a visitor to your site.

Comment: I know that, but they include JavaScript in the page and have a history that isn't trustable. Thanks, but sociable is what I was looking for and I would never use the AddThis service.